# Facebook Messenger Bot - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-messenger

I am using the ruby gem 'messenger-bot', I have successfully setup my webhook but I am not sure how I begin to start receiving and sending messages, any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You should show the effort you've made so far and be sure to ask a specific question to avoid question which are too broad. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You could follow this:

```
Messenger::Bot.config do |config|
  config.access_token = <ACCESS_TOKEN>
  config.validation_token = <VERIFY_TOKEN>
end

#config/routes.rb

mount Messenger::Bot::Space => "/webhook"
```

Example:

```
# app/controllers/messenger_bot_controller.rb

class MessengerBotController < ActionController::Base
  def message(event, sender)
    # profile = sender.get_profile
    sender.reply({ text: "Reply: #{event['message']['text']}" })
  end

  def delivery(event, sender)
    #BlahBlah
  end

  def postback(event, sender)
    #BlahBlah
  end
end
```

[Source](https://github.com/jun85664396/messenger-bot-rails)

Comment: How do i send a message tho?

Comment: @AlecJ.Rubin please read this: https://github.com/jun85664396/messenger-bot-rails and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference#received_message

Comment: Still not figuring this out? Where do i need to place the code in order to send a message when someone messages the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library [Fabychy](https://github.com/nkaviani/fabychy) to manage sending and parsing your Facebook bot in ruby.

Please check the lib and let me know, if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has very informative and easy to follow docs. So, the [official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart) have you covered.

Basically, you need to:

1. Create a Facebook App and Facebook Page
2. Setup Webhook
3. Get Page Access Token
4. Subscribe the App to the Page
5. etc.

Once you have subscribed your webhooks, you can send text/chat messages to your bot/page and they will be delivered to your webhooks. You decide what to do with them next...

Comment: After I set up the web hook, How do i start creating responses?

Comment: User [Send API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference). Seriously, read the docs. They are quite good.

Comment: I'm still having trouble, can you give me an idea of what I need to do and where it goes? How do i write the code to listen to the Facebook web hook in ruby, where do i define these functions?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a self-plug, but I created the [message_quickly](https://github.com/tinkerbox/message_quickly) gem to do this. It goes further than most other gems because it also includes a rails engine to receive callbacks from Facebook Messenger Platform.